# How do I search a list of dictionaries using partial string matching and not be case sensitive, then display results?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a dictionary of two lists created by importing a csv file. Each of the two lists contain multiple lists of dictionaries with 8 key:value pairs per item. Each dictionary contains information about one particular item. One of the lists is information about multiple books; the other is information about multiple movies.

I need to query through the list of books by allowing a user to enter a query string which will be used to search against multiple fields in the list of books. The search needs to perform partial string matching and be case insensitive. All details for all matching books should be displayed without repeating any entries.

How do I search through a list and print the entire dictionary if it matches the query string?

```
# Note to self: book_collection is a list
# ORDER OF INFO in book_collection: title, author, publisher, pages, year, copies, available, ID
def query_book_collection(book_collection):
    # check to see if the string is in the dictionary--partial string matching and case insensitive
    query_string = input("Enter a query string to use for the search: ")

   if query_string.lower() in book_collection:
        print(book_collection)
   else:
        print("Sorry, that search returned no results.")
```

With the way I have it coded now, I expected it to match only full, direct matches (not partial string matches) and then print the full book_collection; however, it only ever prints "Sorry, that search returned no results."

**EDIT:** I have updated query_string.lower to query_string.lower().

The dictionary of books has 22 lists, and each list is a dictionary, I believe. One list (from the debugger) looks like this, for example:

: {'Title': 'My Best Book Ever', 'Author': 'Joseph Caldwell', 'Publisher': 'FPG Publishing', 'Pages': '317', 'Year': '2014', 'Copies': 3, 'Available': 3, 'ID': 17001}

The goal is to be able to search for any phrase, and if that phrase appears in the dictionary above, the entire dictionary will be printed.

Here is more of the code to give a bigger context, for those asking. The code I shared originally is just below the long print menu:

```
# each subset of the collection.
def load_collections():
    # Load the two collections.
    book_collection, max_book_id = load_collection("books.csv")
    movie_collection, max_movie_id = load_collection("movies.csv")

    # Check for error.
    if book_collection is None or movie_collection is None:
        return None, None

    # Return the composite dictionary.
    return {"books": book_collection, "movies": movie_collection}, max(max_book_id, max_movie_id)


# Loads a single collection and returns the data as a list.  Upon error, None is returned.
def load_collection(file_name):
    max_id = -1
    try:
        # Create an empty collection.
        collection = []

        # Open the file and read the field names
        collection_file = open(file_name, "r")
        field_names = collection_file.readline().rstrip().split(",")

        # Read the remaining lines, splitting on commas, and creating dictionaries (one for each item)
        for item in collection_file:
            field_values = item.rstrip().split(",")
            collection_item = {}
            for index in range(len(field_values)):
                if (field_names[index] == "Available") or (field_names[index] == "Copies") or (field_names[index] == "ID"):
                    collection_item[field_names[index]] = int(field_values[index])
                else:
                    collection_item[field_names[index]] = field_values[index]
            # Add the full item to the collection.
            collection.append(collection_item)
            # Update the max ID value
            max_id = max(max_id, collection_item["ID"])

        # Close the file now that we are done reading all of the lines.
        collection_file.close()

    # Catch IO Errors, with the File Not Found error the primary possible problem to detect.
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found when attempting to read", file_name)
        return None
    except IOError:
        print("Error in data file when reading", file_name)
        return None

    # Return the collection.
    return collection, max_id


# Display the menu of commands and get user's selection.  Returns a string with the user's requested command.
# No validation is performed.
def prompt_user_with_menu():
    print("\n\n********** Welcome to the Collection Manager. **********")
    print("COMMAND         FUNCTION")
    print("  ci         Check in an item")
    print("  co         Check out an item")
    print("  ab         Add a new book")
    print("  am         Add a new movie")
    print("  db         Display books")
    print("  dm         Display movies")
    print("  qb         Query for books")
    print("  qm         Query for movies")
    print("  x          Exit")
    return input("Please enter a command to proceed: ")

# Create the query function. Prompts user to enter query string for a book and
# displays ALL results--partial string matching and case insensitive. Note to self: book_collection is a list
# ORDER OF INFO in book_collection: title, author, publisher, pages, year, copies, available, ID
def query_book_collection(book_collection):
    # check to see if the string is in the dictionary--partial string matching and case insensitive
    query_string = input("Enter a query string to use for the search: ")

    if query_string.lower() in book_collection:
        print(book_collection)
    else:
        print("Sorry, that search returned no results.")

def query_movie_collection():
    pass

def check_out():
    pass

def check_in():
    pass

def get_item_ID():
    pass

def display_collection():
    pass

def add_book():
    pass

def add_movie():
    pass


# This is the main program function.  It runs the main loop which prompts the user and performs the requested actions.
def main():
    # Load the collections, and check for an error.
    library_collections, max_existing_id = load_collections()

    if library_collections is None:
        print("The collections could not be loaded. Exiting.")
        return
    print("The collections have loaded successfully.")

    # Display the error and get the operation code entered by the user.  We perform this continuously until the
    # user enters "x" to exit the program.  Calls the appropriate function that corresponds to the requested operation.
    operation = prompt_user_with_menu()
    while operation != "x":
         if operation == "ci":
             check_in(library_collections)
         elif operation == "co":
             check_out(library_collections)
         elif operation == "ab":
             max_existing_id = add_book(library_collections["books"], max_existing_id)
         elif operation == "am":
             max_existing_id = add_movie(library_collections["movies"], max_existing_id)
         elif operation == "db":
             display_collection(library_collections["books"])
         elif operation == "dm":
             display_collection(library_collections["movies"])
         elif operation == "qb":
             query_book_collection(library_collections["books"])
         elif operation == "qm":
             query_movie_collection(library_collections["movies"])
         else:
             print("Unknown command.  Please try again.")

    operation = prompt_user_with_menu()

# Start the program.
main()
```

Comment: `query_string.lower()` rather than `query_string.lower`

Comment: Could you add as well your sample dictionary  ?

Comment: Is it a list or a dict

Comment: "How do I search through a list and print the entire dictionary...?" is ambiguous. How are items in the list related to the dictionary? Perhaps you need to show us the data.

Comment: Have you checked the content of `query_string` and `book_collection` when you get "Sorry, that...."? 2 `print` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To match sub-strings you need to check each value of each book separately. This can be done with a loop and list comprehension:

```
found = False
for book in book_collection:
    if any([query_string.lower() in str(val).lower() for val in book.values()]):
        print(book_collection)
        found == True
if not found:
    print("Sorry, that search returned no results.")
```

The `str(val)` is required as some data in book_collection is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could join all values in collection together before use `in` opearator:

```py
def query_book_collection(book_collection):
    query_string = input("Enter a query string to use for the search: ")
    collection_string = ",".join(map(str, book_collection.values())).lower()

    if query_string.lower() in collection_string:
        print(book_collection)
    else:
        print("Sorry, that search returned no results.")
```

but the more efficient way should be adding a new property which concat all the values for querying into `book_collection` when you load your collection in your `load_collection` function. like(using python buildin `csv` module to read csv file):

```py
def load_collection(file_name):
    try:
        with open(file_name, "r") as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            collection = []
            max_id = -1

            for item in reader:
                # add a field for querying
                item["_fulltext"] = ",".join(item.values())

                # casting type
                item["Available"] = int(item["Available"])
                item["Copies"] = int(item["Copies"])
                item["ID"] = int(item["ID"])

                collection.append(item)
                max_id = max(max_id, item["ID"])

            return collection, max_id

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found when attempting to read", file_name)
        return None, None
    except IOError:
        print("Error in data file when reading", file_name)
        return None, None
```

then, you query function would be like:

```py
def query_book_collection(book_collection):
    query_string = input("Enter a query string to use for the search: ")

    if query_string.lower() in book_collection["_fulltext"]:
        print(book_collection)
    else:
        print("Sorry, that search returned no results.")
```